# How to correctly choose languages support in Windows Phone 8 project?

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

**Environment**:
Win 8.1 Pro upodate 1
VS2013 Ultimate
Windows Phone 8 project

I need to add french support in my projects, and here comes the problem?
I see lots of french options in the Supported Culture, with English and French... The picture is as below

**my questions are**:

1. What's differences between [French] and [French(Monaca)]? Is the
   [French] option equals to a base class?
2. What does [francais] mean there? I notice that there is a [French] but there is not a
   [francais]. What's difference between the two? Why Microsoft adds a
   French options in French language?
3. If I want to support French, What
   should I do? Can I only choose the [French] to meet my requirement?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Every culture/language has base culture, in case of French, French is base culture and will work for all other subcultures of french like french(Monaca) etc...
2. I guess for some language/culture setting on your machine is showing culture names in both language as I cannot see Francais in my VS2013(Ultimage with update 2).
3. I think selecting French or Francais is the same.

P:S your question states **Correctly chose language support** but here you are selection only culture. to correctly support language in windows phone 8 go to WMAppManifest.xaml(Project properties) and select Packaing tab and select Supported languages you want to support in your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any differences between (languages in WMAppManifest) and (Supported Cultures in the project property)? After I modifying the Supported Cultures in the project property. VS2013 will auto-add the language code in WMAppManifest.xml.